# NumPy np.zeros() cannot interpret multi-dimensional shape as a data type

Tags: python, numpy

Here's the code I want to run :

```
print(np.zeros(3, 2))
```

If I'm not wrong it should return :

```
[[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.]]
```

But instead,  get this error :

```
    print(np.zeros(3,2))
TypeError: Cannot interpret '2' as a data type
```

And when I try running this :

```
print(np.zeros(3,))
```

It worked perfectly find and return the output as I expected

How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: The argument needs to be a tuple ```print(np.zeros((3,2)))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)' argument *shape* should be

> int or tuple of ints

so in your case

```
print(np.zeros((3,2)))
```

If you do `np.zeros(3,2)` this mean you want `dtype` (*The desired data-type for the array*) to be `2` which does not make sense.